# How can I change the path that "rbenv init" uses?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to install rbenv and then run `rbenv install -v 2.3.1` to install the corresponding Ruby version.

However the quota in my home folder is really low and I can't use it currently as the admin doesn't allow it. By default when I execute `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` it creates the .rbenv in my home folder.

Is there any way to create it in /opt or anywhere else?

Comment: If the admin doesn't allow it in your home directory due to space concerns, then they're not likely to allow you to put it in /opt or anywhere else. Talk to the admin and see if you can get your space increased. Don't try an end-run; That trick never ends well.

Comment: You're right. In this special case though /opt is our playground for some reason.

Comment: /opt is somewhat like /local in that the system doesn't own it. All the sysadms that I've known (myself included) wouldn't let anything be written to either directory on shared systems if there was a disk space concern. But, if they have a lot of space allocated to /opt then I can see making it writable by users instead of their home directories. They're all variations on different poisons we brew when managing and using shared hosts. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you trying setting `RBENV_ROOT` as documented in the [rbenv README](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#environment-variables)?

```
export RBENV_ROOT=/opt/rbenv
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Comment: Thanks, I kind of missed that. Haven't tried it yet but I'm sure it will work.